# Any open source method to isolate/sandbox tomcat web apps?

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

We have an in-house hosting of many web apps on our single tomcat instance on RHEL Linux.

Is there some open source JVM/Catalina modification that would enact a security/sandbox feature and allow us to restrict what file paths the container can read/write to?

Also some way to prevent sandboxed code from loading non-white-listed classes?

Comment: "feature ... to restrict what file paths the container can read/write to": [Operating system file security](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Step_by_Step_Guide/s1-navigating-ownership.html). Even if you *also* apply some kind of Java sandboxing, you always do this.

Comment: Oh yes, absolutely, basic permissions are in place. tomcat is running in its own user permission session and can't elevate up. However, we're more concerned with one of the web apps, written by various developers, becoming compromised and giving access to files in the communal storage where each app is writing under its own directory. A jvm-level sandbox to prevent such r/w permissions would immensely prevent this possible exposure.

Comment: Have you looked into the Security Manager built into Java?

Comment: have you considered simply running the untrusted application in a separate tomcat instance on a separate user? that way you can leverage OS security mechanisms.